# Is there a directory for public servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How do I find public Minecraft servers?
Is there a directory of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no *official* directory for Minecraft servers, but the most popular places are:

[Minecraft Classic Servers](http://www.minecraft.net/servers.jsp)
[Minecraft Alpha Servers](http://servers.minecraftforum.net/)

Comment: the last one looks identical to http://mcserverlist.net/

Comment: Jader Dias: It's the same site.

Comment: This answer is out of date.

Answer (score 6):

The [official Minecraft forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewforum.php?f=1014) encourage people to list their SMP servers.

Also, anyone running [MCAdmin](http://www.mcadmin.eu/Main_Page) with the server list option turned on will appear in [this list](http://list.mcadmin.eu/).  if it's in there it's almost certainly public.

Comment: You now have enough rep :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Abyssal-Legion Minecraft Server Status Page](http://minecraft.abyssal-legion.com/serverstatus/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to start one myself. Sorry for the shameless plug, if it's not allowed please remove :)

http://minepal.com

No servers yet, but it's going to be the most fully featured.

Comment: great initiative, I hope you can gather the best list. please comment here when you have it ready.

Comment: I see that you added some servers: http://minepal.com/servers

Comment: Those are sketchy, to say the least. I've still got loads of work to do on the site!